# Disable intensity rescale in scipy.imsave

Tags: image, matlab, scipy

When I save an image in scipy using `scipy.misc.imsave`, it always "normalizes" the image intensities, scaling the lowest value to 0 and the highest to 1 (for grayscale), comparable to what MATLAB does with the `[]` argument in `imshow(image, [])`. Is there a way to disable this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found this: http://stefaanlippens.net/scipy_unscaledimsave

Comment: Thanks, this is what I ended up doing, converting to a PIL image manually.

Comment: The solution is `scipy.toimage(a, cmin=0, cmax=255).save("tmp.png")` in case the link goes south.

Comment: So how do we read with the same scale without scaling the values while reading it ?